# Windows 8 Client unable to open specific folder of SMB share from OSX Mountain Lion Server - every other share from same server is fine

Tags: mac-osx, network-share, server-message-block, windows-8, osx-mountain-lion

After spending almost 3 days on this issue without any idea how to solve it or finding similar problems on serverfault and other communities, I guess I have to open a question. Here's the problem:

We work in a pure Mac environment, however for some applications and machines we need a few Windows PCs. Up until now they have all used Windows XP as OS, however we recently built a fresh Windows client and decided to go ahead with Windows 8.

Data for those 3 to 4 Windows boxes is served from a Mac Mini running Mountain Lion Server. The share in questions is an external RAID-System attached to the Mac Mini / Server. We will call this one "ShareX".

- On our Mac clients everything is and has been fine - naturally, AFP is used for file sharing on these clients though.
- On our Windows XP boxes and virtual machines everything is fine as well
- On the new Windows 8 box \\server\ShareX is not reachable:

  - the progress bar in the location field on this client will progress into eternity when trying to access this share, until explorer.exe becomes unresponsive
  - meanwhile \\server\ShareA, ShareB or ShareC are accessible without problems
  - even subfolder of ShareX are working fine, e.g. \\server\ShareX\SubfolderY - so only the root of the share seems to be affected
  - for testing I also installed Windows 8 in a virtual machine -> exactly the same issues
  - we have another Windows 7 based controller PC, which behaves as flawless as the XP systems - can access everything
- oddly enough in about 1 out of 30 times I can access the problematic share, however if I open another subfolder and try to go back to the root of the share explorer.exe is unresponsive again.

This is what I tried:

- killed and restarted the smb sharing service
- restarted the server
- deleted and recreated the share
- just for testing also served the share via FTP, which Windows 8 could access just fine. So it's only related to SMB, not the data itself it seems.
- checked the external raid system for errors. Everything's ok according to Apple's Disk Utility

At this point I'm really out of ideas. Any help is appreciated.

Has anyone come across a similar problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nevermind...I went ahead and replaced Apple's Samba implementation with [SMBup](http://eduo.info/apps/smbup) which fetches the current official Samba release and deactivates Apple's SMB service.

Everything worked instantly and my shares are now accessible from XP to Windows 8 on all machines.

In case anyone else experiences problems with the SMB service in OSX, this could be an alternative.